# HTML/CSS Using ttf fonts via unicode + classes in CSS

Tags: html, css, unicode, fonts

I've ran into a bit of trouble trying to use my .ttf font via classes in CSS. The problem is that nothing gets displayed. I've loaded the .ttf font file and created a CSS class for this specific icon from the .ttf font file. All the available information I have is this, regarding this specific icon:

Glyph: 5
Character# : 97
Unicode: 0061
a

```css
@font-face {
font-family: 'remoglyph';
    src:url('../RemoGlyphs.ttf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

[class^="icon-"]:before,
[class*=" icon-"]:before {
    font-family: 'remoglyph';
    font-style: normal;
    speak: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.icon-arrowdown:before {
    content: "\e0061";
}
```

```html
<i class="icon-arrowdown"></i>
```

Above you can see my CSS and HTML source.

Thanks for any advice in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake, sorry guys..

```
content: "\0061"
```

Thanks anyway :)

Comment: To be sure to be truly cross-browser you should use different font formats... You can, for example, use this online convertion tool  (http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) and follow its css rules to load them all.